# enabling smarter text wrapping in a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

**The Context**

At the moment, I have a JTextArea that has been created like so:

```
JTextArea descArea = new JTextArea();
descArea.setFont(style.getFont());
descArea.setLineWrap(true);
descArea.setName("descArea");
descArea.setToolTipText(resourceMap.getString("descArea.toolTipText"));
descArea.setText(model.getName());
JScrollPane descPane = new JScrollPane(descArea,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

When a user types something into the field, it does indeed wrap (as per `descArea.setLineWrap(true)`), but does it a little clumsily by breaking words like the following example:

[image]

The users of our software are expecting the wrapping to be a little more clever and automatically generate something more like:

[image]

With the general idea being that when they type the last 'th' it all moves down to the second line along with the insertion point as they type (in a way similar to just about every other text editor).

---

**The Question**

My initial thought had been to implement this sort of wrapping manually using a Key Listener, but I was wondering if there is a better approach/different component that could achieve this functionality more easily?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is already implemented.

```
  textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```